# Colloquial for House of Commons

Tags: word-usage, british-english

In the United Kingdom, what is colloquial for House of Commons? Would you say a member addressed the House, addressed Commons, or would you also say he or she addressed the House of Commons?

Answer (score 1):

Where it is obvious which house is being referenced you could just say ***the House*** - with a capital H.

Where distinction is necessary one normally sees ***the Commons*** - but remember it always takes the definite article.

You can of course give it its full moniker *the House of Commons*.

If you are needing to stress that something actually happened in the Chamber, as opposed to somewhere around the members' lobby, offices etc - you could say either *in the Chamber* or *on the Floor of the House*.

All of the above applies equally in the case of the House of Lords. Together they constitute *Parliament*.

Comment: Thank you. Would you capitalize "members." As in "The members walked to across the yard." (I've already used MPs elsewhere and want to change it up a bit.)

Comment: Given it is the House of Commons I think I would capitalise *Members*. If it was my local golf club, I wouldn't. Others may disagree.

Comment: As you've mentioned crossing a yard, it's worth pointing out that 'crossing the House (of Commons)' has a particular symbolic meaning. You should only use that if someone is dramatically changing their political allegiance, not if they are simply walking across the Chamber.

Comment: @JHCL It isn't a 'yard' which the members cross - it is the floor of the house. The Government and Opposition benches face one another. If someone 'crosses the floor' they transfer their allegiance from one to the other. In the Post-War Labour Government of 1945, one of their ministers was Sir Hartley Shawcross. So close to the Opposition did he begin to appear that he was dubbed *Sir Shortly Floorcross* by elements of the media.

Comment: The "yard" was arbitrary. I didn't mean to allude to anything!